# PHP HTML form not uploading data to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am creating a social site and I am trying to add a comment under a post.

When I try to add it from the comment_frame.php(where all of the comment code is) the comment uploads properly. But when I try to add a comment from the index.php page to the comment_frame.php page, nothing goes into the database and I don't get any errors. My code is below.

comment_frame.php(the code that works):

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'] ?? 0;

<form class='comment_frame.php' id='single_form' name='postComment<?php echo $post_id; ?>' 
    method='POST'>

    <textarea name='post_body' rows="3" placeholder='Write a comment...'></textarea>

    <input type='submit' name='postComment<?php echo $post_id; ?>' value='Post'>

</form>

if(isset($_POST['postComment' . $post_id])) {

        if (empty($_POST["post_body"])) {

            // echo "Comment can't be empty";
            echo "Comment can't be empty. <a href=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].">Try Again</a>";
            //die() also terminates the script with display the message.
            exit();
        }

        $post_body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['post_body'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (post_body, posted_by, posted_to, post_id) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $post_body, $userLoggedIn, $posted_to, $post_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($posted_to != $userLoggedIn) {

            $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
            $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $posted_to, 'comment');
        }

            $get_commenters = $con->prepare('SELECT post_body, posted_by, posted_to, date_added 
                FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY date_added DESC');

            $get_commenters->bind_param("i", $post_id);
            $get_commenters->execute();
            $get_commenters->bind_result($post_body, $posted_by, $posted_to, $date_added);
            $get_commenters_result = $get_commenters->get_result();
            $notified_users = array();

            while ($row = $get_commenters_result->fetch_assoc()) {

            if($row['posted_by'] != $posted_to && $row['posted_by'] != $user_to 
                && $row['posted_by'] != $userLoggedIn && !in_array($row['posted_by'], $notified_users)) {

                $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
                $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $row['posted_by'], "comment_non_owner");

                array_push($notified_users, $row['posted_by']);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The code that doesn't work:

index.php:

```
<div class='comment_div'>

                            <form target='frame' class='comment_frame.php?post_id=$post_id' 
                            id='comment_form' name='postComment" . $post_id . "' 
                            method='POST'>

                                <textarea name='post_body' placeholder='Write a comment...'></textarea>

                                <input type='submit' name='postComment" . $post_id . "' 
                                value='". $post_id ."'>

                            </form>

                        </div>
```

comment_frame.php:

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'] ?? 0;

if(isset($_POST['postComment' . $post_id])) {

        if (empty($_POST["post_body"])) {

            // echo "Comment can't be empty";
            echo "Comment can't be empty. <a href=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].">Try Again</a>";
            //die() also terminates the script with display the message.
            exit();
        }

        $post_body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['post_body'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (post_body, posted_by, posted_to, post_id) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $post_body, $userLoggedIn, $posted_to, $post_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($posted_to != $userLoggedIn) {

            $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
            $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $posted_to, 'comment');
        }

            $get_commenters = $con->prepare('SELECT post_body, posted_by, posted_to, date_added 
                FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY date_added DESC');

            $get_commenters->bind_param("i", $post_id);
            $get_commenters->execute();
            $get_commenters->bind_result($post_body, $posted_by, $posted_to, $date_added);
            $get_commenters_result = $get_commenters->get_result();
            $notified_users = array();

            while ($row = $get_commenters_result->fetch_assoc()) {

            if($row['posted_by'] != $posted_to && $row['posted_by'] != $user_to 
                && $row['posted_by'] != $userLoggedIn && !in_array($row['posted_by'], $notified_users)) {

                $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
                $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $row['posted_by'], "comment_non_owner");

                array_push($notified_users, $row['posted_by']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful for you to identify the problem more specifically.  That a script doesn't work is a bit broad.  Have you checked what does work and where it fails/doesn't do as you expect.

Comment: Well, I know the `post_id` isn't empty because I use it as the value for the submit buttons.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav Yeah I tried changing it to action and it still did nothing.

Comment: `action` is right. You are making this request as `GET`, Since passing `?post_id=$post_id`

Comment: Try passing post_Id in `input type hidden`

Comment: I did this `<input type='hidden' name='comment_frame.php?post_id=$post_id'>` and the form still doesn't submit anything.

Comment: Try `<form target='frame' action='comment_frame.php' id='comment_form' name='postComment" . $post_id . "' method='POST'>
 <input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='". $post_id ."'>
</form>`                    Please check if any error.

Comment: It was a combo of changing this `class='comment_frame.php?post_id=$post_id' ` to this `action='comment_frame.php?post_id=$post_id' ` and passing the `post_id` in a hidden input type

Comment: Stop using`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` it's deprecated

Comment: @Dharman I don't see anywhere that says it's deprecated.

Comment: @sirtoby It's deprecated in PHP 8.1. It hasn't been released yet, but I am already warning you that this filter is basically meaningless and it will be removed soon.

Comment: @Dharman so what's a good alternative ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Dharman I wanna filter and sanitize any user input.

Comment: That's very vague. However, this is a good question in general. Please post a new question and let me know. I will write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of class in form tag use action attribute. <form target='frame' class='comment_frame.php..., use <form action='comment_frame.php'...

```
<form target='frame' action='comment_frame.php?post_id=$post_id' 
                        id='comment_form' name='postComment" . $post_id . "' 
                        method='POST'>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
//put this code in the index.php

    <form action="comment_frame.php"  id='single_form' name='postComment' 
        method='POST'>
        
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" name="post_id">
        <textarea name='post_body' required rows="3" placeholder='Write a comment...'></textarea>
    
        <input type='submit' name='postComment<?php echo $post_id; ?>' value='Post'>
    
    </form>
    
    //put this code in the comment_frame.php
    
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    
    if(isset($_POST['postComment' . $post_id])) {
    
            if (empty($_POST["post_body"])) {
    
                // echo "Comment can't be empty";
                echo "Comment can't be empty. <a href=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].">Try Again</a>";
                //die() also terminates the script with display the message.
                exit();
            }
    
            $post_body = trim(strip_tags(filter_var($_POST['post_body'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (post_body, posted_by, posted_to, post_id) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $post_body, $userLoggedIn, $posted_to, $post_id);
            $stmt->execute();
    
            if($posted_to != $userLoggedIn) {
    
                $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
                $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $posted_to, 'comment');
            }
    
                $get_commenters = $con->prepare('SELECT post_body, posted_by, posted_to, date_added 
                    FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY date_added DESC');
    
                $get_commenters->bind_param("i", $post_id);
                $get_commenters->execute();
                $get_commenters->bind_result($post_body, $posted_by, $posted_to, $date_added);
                $get_commenters_result = $get_commenters->get_result();
                $notified_users = array();
    
                while ($row = $get_commenters_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
                if($row['posted_by'] != $posted_to && $row['posted_by'] != $user_to 
                    && $row['posted_by'] != $userLoggedIn && !in_array($row['posted_by'], $notified_users)) {
    
                    $notification = new Notification($con, $userLoggedIn);
                    $notification->insertNotification($post_id, $row['posted_by'], "comment_non_owner");
    
                    array_push($notified_users, $row['posted_by']);
                }
        }
    }
```